# Defs pattern with css module - modify point in c3.js line chart to have an image inside

Tags: reactjs, c3.js, css-modules

I am using c3.js and my components are using CSS Modules. I wanted to modify the fill of points in the line chart with an image. For that in the render method I had added defs-pattern -

```
render(){
    return (
          <div>
            <defs>
              <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1">
                <image x="0" y="0" src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/faf2fa/0011ff.png&text=x" />
              </pattern>
            </defs>
            <C3Chart {...this.getConfig()}/>
          </div>
        );
}
```

In the styles css file I had added -

```
container :global(.c3-target-subscriber .c3-circle-5) {
  fill: url(#image) !important;
}
```

But nothing happens. I just want to show an image inside the point of the line chart.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<defs>` element must have a parent that is a SVG element and not a HTML element. You need something like this:

```
<svg>
  <defs>
    <pattern id="image" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" height="1" width="1">
       <image x="0" y="0" src="http://dummyimage.com/20x20/faf2fa/0011ff.png&text=x" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
<svg>
```

Also your CSS points to something with a id of gradient but your pattern's id is image.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not solve the problem. It is w.r.t css module and I wanted to know how to have this working with css module in react.

Comment: It certainly solves one of your problems. Perhaps you have others in which case you'll need to create a [mcve]